# Should I own up to posting questions on Chegg?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cheating, canada

So long story short, I'm a current studying biomedical sciences at a Canadian university (University A), and I ended up posting some questions on Chegg last year. I can't get them removed, but haven't been caught yet. I was under a lot of stress mental health wise with online school, but what I did was still wrong and I really regret it. But I guess I got what I deserved and failed the course anyways.

The policy at my school is that if I get a transcript notation, it is erased 4 years after the offense or 1 year after graduation.

I'm also thinking of switching out to a community college to do a technician's diploma and maybe coming back to finish my undergrad somewhere else (University B) in maybe 4 years because I'm interested in grad school, but I know the technician's diploma will help me with making some money NOW to pay off my loans.

What I'm worried about now is this coming back to haunt me in 5-6 years if they go hunting for old assignment questions and I have finished undergrad at University B, leaving me with a black mark on my transcript for 4 years and unable to apply for grad school.

I think it might just be the smart decision from a long-term perspective to finish up now so that even if I get hit with a transcript notation, it will only last for 1 year after I graduate. Also, after dropping out of University A, would they even bother to give me an academic offense? And even if they did, wouldn't it just be automatically erased according to the policy?

Alternatively, I would like to just own up and confess to the prof about this even though it's been a while and while this may lead to the black mark, this would help me a lot with the guilt I'm experiencing and leave less uncertainty in the future for me long term and maybe this is the way to go.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think any professor has the time to search for old assignment questions posted by a specific student years after the fact.

Comment: Hi confusion, welcome to Ac.SE. Your post is quite long so I tried to tidy it up but that left me with some questions, which I'll post in separate comments so they can be deleted as they are addressed.

Comment: 1) "*The policy at my school is that if I get a transcript notation, it is erased in four years or one year after graduation.*" You suggest dropping out so it goes away in one year, not four. Is the policy one year after **graduation** or one year after **leaving the university**?

Comment: 2) Why would they go hunting for old exam questions, and how would they know who posted them?

Comment: 3) By "charges," do you mean legal charges?

Comment: 4) Ac.SE tries to focus on single, answerable questions. Your question is really riding the line of answerable questions and personal-decision questions. I'd suggest trying to focus your question, but note that we can't answer things about your university's policies, not in the least because we don't know them.

Comment: 5) Not knowing how Chegg works, I assume you mean you posted questions from a test on Chegg?

Comment: @confusion_time But how would they know where to look? Does Chegg say "questions supplied by confusion_time at the University of Toronto"?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it's effectively unanswerable without answers to some of the questions that Azor has raised. Since OP hasn't been seen here in a while, I'd say these answers are not forthcoming. So, closing.